# php rounding numbers

Tags: php, rounding

Actually, "rounding" may not be the best name to describe what I'm looking to do.

I want to round only floats that have zeros after the decimal point:  ".00"

I don't want to display any decimal numbers if there are zeros after the decimal point.
Normally I'd just look for ".00" in the variable, and if it has what I'm looking for I just strip it out.  However, there are a few instances that the decimal might be longer than 2 places.  like:  45.000 or 56.0000

I didn't want to mess with any regex on this if there was a php function that stripped out the extra zeros, if they exist.

Comment: What about "4.50"? Should that become "4.5"?

Comment: Clarification: I am assuming that you are trying to read in a value, then write the value with as few trailing 0s as possible. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `floatval()` might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: This does it.  Seems I need to convert the string to an int or float.  I didn't think that it was in a string and needed conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `round($f,2);`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

For that genius who downvoted: http://codepad.org/2bBA5UpL